# How to display a database table on to the table in the JSP page

Tags: mysql, jsp

- My problem is that the table in my database is not able to be displayed at the table in my JSP page.
- I find this code totally right but dont know y m not getting the output right.
- Please tell me what is the problem.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                                                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  <form method="post">

  <table border="2">
  <tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>NAME</td>
  <td>SKILL</td>
  <td>ACTION</td>
  </tr>
  <%
  try
  {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
  String username="root";
  String password="root";
  String query="select * from jsp1";
  Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
  Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while(rs.next())
  {

  %>
      <tr><td><%rs.getInt("ID"); %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%rs.getString("NAME"); %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%rs.getString("SKILL"); %></td></tr>
          <%

  }
  %>
      </table>
      <%
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
      }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }




  %>

  </form>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is very simple. If you want to display value in JSP, you have to use <%=  %> tag instead of <% %>, here is the solved code:

`<tr>
    <td><%=rs.getInt("ID") %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("NAME") %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("SKILL") %></td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 2):

you can also print the data onto your HTML/JSP document.
like:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jsp Sample</title>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*;"%>
</head>
<body bgcolor=yellow>
    <%
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forum","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student;");
    %><table border=1 align=center style="text-align:center">
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>NAME</th>
             <th>SKILL</th>
             <th>ACTION</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <%while(rs.next())
        {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("id") %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString("name") %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString("skill") %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString("action") %></td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
           </tbody>
        </table><br>
    <%}
    catch(Exception e){
        out.print(e.getMessage());%><br><%
    }
    finally{
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
    %>
</body>
</html>

<!--executeUpdate() mainupulation and executeQuery() for retriving-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Tracking ID
            
            Track

```
    <br>
    <%String id = request.getParameter("track_id");%>
       <%if (id.length() == 0) {%>
    <b><h1>Please Enter Tracking ID</h1></b>
    <% } else {%>
    <div class="container">
        <table border="1" class="table" >
            <thead>
                <tr class="warning" >
                    <td ><h4>Track ID</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>Source</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>Destination</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>Current Status</h4></td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <%
                try {
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    String sql = "select * from track where track_id="+ id;
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
            %>
            <tr class="info">
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("track_id")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("source")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("destination")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("status")%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                    }
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            %>
        </table>

        <%}%>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

After few googling I found this solution.

```
    <sql:setDataSource var = "snapshot" driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edyoda"
                  user = "root"  password = "xxxxx"/>
    <sql:query dataSource = "${snapshot}" var = "result">
             SELECT * FROM exam;
    </sql:query>

    <table border = "1" width = "100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Total Marks</th>
            <th>Percentage</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value = "${row.id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value = "${row.firstName}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value = "${row.lastName}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value = "${row.semester}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value = "${row.totalMarks}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value = "${row.percentage}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).