# java web app - best way to get results from a MySQL table and display on web

Tags: java, web-applications

I am creating a simple web app where my main goal is to retrieve records from a table in MySQL and display the results on the web (front-end).

I wrote a simple program in Intellij where my index.jsp looks like below:

```
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    form.example input[type=text] {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      float: left;
      width: 80%;
      background: #f1f1f1;
    }

    form.example button {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #2196F3;
      color: white;
      font-size: 18px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-left: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    form.example button:hover {
      background: #0b7dda;
    }

    form.example::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    #result{
      padding-top: 30px;
      width:40%;
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      left:35%;

    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
    }

    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }

    li a:active{

    }


  </style>



  <title>File Queue table</title>
  <body>
  <h1>Simple File Queue table</h1>



  </body>

<script>

  function queue_display(){




  }






</script>




</html>
```

MyServlet.java :

```
  @WebServlet(name = "MyServlet")
        public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



            }





            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

           response.setContentType("text/html");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


         try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.11:3306/test", "root", "root");
         String sql ="Select * from filequeue;";
         statement = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

     while(resultSet.next()){

     // display each record
       resultSet.getString("UniqueID");
         resultSet.getString("FilePath");
         resultSet.getString("Status");
         resultSet.getString("DateTime");
         resultSet.getString("Error");
         list.add(resultSet);
     }

 resultSet.close();
     statement.close();
     conn.close();
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
     request.setAttribute("queryResults",list);
     dispatcher.forward(request,response);

     }catch(Exception e){

     System.out.println(e);

     }
        }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">


    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> MyServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

I am new to web application, is there an efficient way to retrieve records from table and display on front end, without using servlet?

Comment: *web application...efficient way...without using servlet*  Firstly `servlets` are the bread and butter of java web application programming, why would you **not** want to use them?  Next, there are many ways to make your code in-efficient whether you are using `servlets` or not

Comment: I suggest that you step back for a while and re-read some tutorial stuff.  This looks quite good https://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc

Comment: downvoter, any comment?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Servlets helps the web app to get a request , is that right?

Comment: To over-simplify things, the servlet is the web-app, seriously suggest that you read the link I gave you, lots and lots of interesting information.

Comment: Yea i'm gonna read it right now.

Comment: I found another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997285/how-to-display-a-database-table-on-to-the-table-in-the-jsp-page  where it is able to retrieve information without using servlet, is this a bad practice?

Comment: If you read the link I gave you, you would notice *The principle when programming Servlet + JSP
These are the principles that you should keep in mind to be able to build a Web application using   Servlet + JSP  satisfying criteria: code is simple, easy to understand and easy to maintain.
The principles:
Never allow users to directly access to your JSP page.
JSP is only considered as the place to display interface.
Servlet acts as the controller of the application flows and  program logical processing.*

Comment: Can you check my edited post if i am in the right direction? After following your tutorial

Comment: No, you want an https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery() which will return to you a ResultSet

Comment: something like above?

Comment: yeah, something like above

Comment: Is there an API to display the results in the while loop without using get?

Comment: probably what you what is to create your own Data Object class (DO) and have a `List` or them,  that can then be added to your request (or session) and then use JSTL in the JSP to display

Comment: I think the idea is like what i wrote above?

Comment: No, maybe `String f1 = resultSet.getString("UniqueID");` - you can not add the `ResultSet`

Comment: Then I have to add all 5 columns of them in the list

Comment: As I said before *create your own Data Object class (DO)*

Comment: When you have learnt to walk, you may consider using JPA and using the reverse engineering tools available in IDEs such as Eclipse

Comment: Yea web app is still fresh to me. So in my data object class, what must be contain inside?

Answer (score -2):

@DareDevil You can fetch the records from the datastore via ajax call. Whilst form submit is another alternative for making a backend call from jsp, do prefer ajax if you need to load the contents without a page reload. Hope this helps.